# What mean * and &

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Today I read "Pro Objective-C Design Patterns for iOS" by Carlo Chung.
So I read about Adapter Pattern and saw this method declared in protocol:

```
-(void) command: (SetStrokeColorCommand *) command
        didRequestColorComponentsForRed: (CGFloat *) red
                                  green: (CGFloat *) green
                                   blue: (CGFloat *) blue;
```

You can see it on page 115 from book.
Than this method used

```
[delegate_ command:self didRequestColorComponentsForRed: &redValue
                                                  green: &greenValue
                                                   blue: &blueValue];
```

And then declaration of this method on page 118

```
-(void) command: (SetStrokeColorCommand *) command
        didRequestColorComponentsForRed: (CGFloat *) red
                                  green: (CGFloat *) green
                                   blue: (CGFloat *) blue
 {
  *red = [redSlider_ value];
  *green = [greenSlider_ value];
  *blue = [blueSlider_ value];
 }
```

What mean * in declaration (*red, *green, *blue) and what mean & (&redValue...)? I saw & with only &error in code.

Comment: Read some material on Pointer in C or C++.

Comment: & is the address-of operator, * declares a variable as a pointer, or de-references one already declared http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: The only valid answer is to start with a book. I suggest this one: http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/objective-c_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide . It starts with C and then jumps into Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what is it

Comment: You really need to have a fundamental understanding of C before you jump into Objective-C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` is the pointer declarator or dereference operator.
In a declaration, * denotes a pointer variable.

`&` is the address-of operator.

Side note:

You should learn the basics of a language before attempting more advanced books.

Answer (score 2):

As some people have pointed out, these are related to pointers.  There is a whole wealth of information about this, however, if you are new you might find it a little confusing.

To point out what you need to know...

Most of the time you have an input and an output to a function.

```
- (int)roundMyFloat:(float)float;
```

Here the input is a float and the output is a int.

Sometimes you will need more than one output to a method.  A common situation is where you might want to return a error code as well as a success parameter.

```
- (BOOL)doSomthing:(NSError**)error;
```

You would use this like so...

```
NSError* error = nil;
BOOL sucess = [myInstance doSomething:&error];
if (!sucess) 
{
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

You are passing the `error` in as an 'output paramter'.  The code for `doSomthing` will take your error and fill it with information if needed.

You need to declare the error parameter with two `*`'s in the method declaration `(NSError**)` because you are saying you want a pointer to an error object and an error object is actually a pointer itself - so its a pointer to a pointer.

When you pass the error into the method `[myInstance doSomething:&error];` you use the `&` symbol to say 'take the memory address of my error object'.

In your example `red` `green` and `blue` are output parameters.  The method `didRequestColorComponentsForRed` is changing the values you pass in to it. Unlike the `NSError` example, `red` `green` and `blue` are not objects so they only need one star in the method declaration.  This says 'accept a pointer to a `CGFloat` value as a parameter'.

When you invoke the `didRequestColorComponentsForRed` method, you pass in the color components using the `&` symbol just like in the NSError example.  This says take the memory address of my `CGFloat` value and pass it to the function.

Dont worry too much about the `&` and `*` syntax for now - just remember what its for (output parameters).  You should eventually read up about it to work it out (its quite cool actually!).

Hope that helps - and dont be afraid to ask questions.